# How to grab a value from multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to grab one field of database from an array that contains all the data fields here is m code:

```
public function show($id)
    {

        $data['product'] = $this->products_model->get_product_by_id($id);

        foreach ($data['product'] as $row) {
        $seller = $row['seller_id'];
        }

        $data['seller_name'] = $this->members_model->get_members_by_id($seller);

        if (empty($data['product']))
        {
                show_404();
        }

        $data['main_content'] = 'pages/show';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }
```

I think the code is self explanatory what I want is to grab the ***seller_id*** field from the **products** database to use it to grab ***seller_name*** field from **members** database. The code that I thinks it's not working is this part:

```
foreach ($data['product'] as $row) {
        $seller = $row['seller_id'];
    }
```

It gives me this error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: What does the code do? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Don't know what $this->products_model->get_product_by_id($id) returns, but if it returns a row of data from the database as an array then you should be able to set $seller = $data['product']['seller_id'];

Comment: Try this, after that line: `print_r($data['product'])`. I think the array structure is not what you think it is.

Comment: I just added the error message above

Comment: ckimbrell this line code works well it returns an array from database that contains all the fields based on the id that is given

Comment: @mkasberg This array works well its tested and and gives the data in the view page without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys the problem was with the view page, That's how I used the array in the view page and it did work:

```
foreach($seller_name as $row){
    echo'<p class="product-price">'.$row['user_name'].'</p>'; 
    echo'<p class="product-price">'.$row["phone_number"].'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion
```

This message means that you are getting an array and you are considering it as string as you are passing it like string.

So here is condition ,either you are getting multiple values in `$data['product']` and yes that is correct because you are applying foreach there.So make your query in such a way that it will return only one row from products table.that will be solution

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure it gets only one row because as you see in the code above the function has $id parameter so it only gets one row and its tested that's why I'm very sure about that.

Comment: Yes you are right `$id` is passed as 1 parameter at a time but I am talking about  `$data['product'] = $this->products_model->get_product_by_id($id);` which means from this model communication in return you are fetching records in array as you are storing returned values in array  `$data['product']` ;

Answer (score 2):

You don't need foreach loop, just check if `!empty($data['product'])` and use `$data['product']['seler_id']` or `$data['product'][0]['seller_id']` depends how is your model code. So, as you want exact product by id your code should looks like:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $data['product'] = $this->products_model->get_product_by_id($id);

    if (empty($data['product']))
    {
        show_404();
    }
    else
    {
        $seller_id = $data['product']['seller_id'];
        $data['seller_name'] = $this->members_model->get_members_by_id($seller);
        $data['main_content'] = 'pages/show';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }
}
```

One notice here, since you have relations between tables, query in model should contain JOIN section and you would be able get seller details in one query. Basically, your $data['product'] would contain name (and other details from sellers table) in same time or in one query. Check [this link](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Answer (score 1):

use `array_column` to get all `seller_id`'s in one array. just like `var_dump array_column ( $data, 'seller_id' )` .

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you mean can you explain it more

Comment: you want to retrieve `seller_id`, so I helped you to retrieve all `seller_id`'s  in a separate array, if you want it conditionally you need to go through loop.

Comment: Thanks I did search for array_column and i tried this,  `$seller = array_column($product, 'seller_id');` but it gave me the same error

Comment: Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: I don't know if I used your code correctly or not but it gave the same error `$seller = var_dump(array_column($data, 'seller_id'));`

Comment: var_dump( $seller ); and give me the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91208/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-user2682025).